# Iptables: order of redirect and input-filter

Tags: iptables, firewall

I will filter inbound traffic with iptables.

I have 2 goals.

```
a) Allow HTTPS inbound at port 443.

b) Redirect port 443 to process listening port on 9443.
```

Not sure about the processing of that 2 rules.

Do I need to set my INPUT rule to ACCEPT inbound HTTPS to port 443 or 9443?7

Depends on if redirection is done before or after I think.

Comment: you should be able to test that :) put log rules for both ports and see what you catch :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `PREROUTING` chain in the `nat` table handles the redirection for you:

```
iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING --protocol tcp --dport 443 --jump REDIRECT --to-port 9443
```

Then the `INPUT` chain (implicitly in the `filter` table) handles permitted traffic:

```
iptables -I INPUT --protocol tcp --dport 9443 --jump ACCEPT
```

Notice that the result is that the service listening on port 9443 will effectively accept traffic on both its true port 9443 and the alternative 443.